# How do I evaluate $\frac{b^{-4}}{b^{-4}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know this is very basic, but when evaluating

$\frac{b^{-4}}{b^{-4}}$

Apparently I cannot write it as $\frac{b^4}{b^4}$ by moving the expressions to make them positive. Why can't I do that?
The answer is supposed to be $b^8$ not 1, like I originally thought.

Comment: The answer is $1$.

Comment: I think you understanding is incorrect. That is clearly 1, ($b \ne 0$).  The only way that is $b^8$ is the question is $\frac{b^4}{b^{-4}}$

Comment: I was looking at my sister's math HW, and I told her it's 1, but apparently that was wrong. That's why I was confused.

Comment: Well whoever told you it was not 1 was wrong.

Comment: Okay, oops I made a mistake. Apparently it was $\frac{b^{-4}}{b^4}$ I accidently thought it was a negative. My apologies and thank you all for your help.

Comment: Then it is $b^{-8}$, or $\frac{1}{b^8}$.

Answer (score 3):

Simply because $x/x=1$ for all non zero real numbers. $\frac {b^{-4}}{b^{-4}}$ is an expression of the form $x/x$ (assuming $b\neq0$) and so it equals $1$. One can show this using this other method: $$\frac{b^{-4}}{b^{-4}}={b^{-4}}\frac1{b^{-4}}={b^{-4}}{b^{4}}=b^{-4+4}=b^0=1$$

It is however $b^{-8}$ if $\dfrac{b^{-4}}{b^4}$ which can be shown using the method above.

I hope this helps.
Best wishes, $\mathcal H$akim.

Comment: Thanks @amWhy ! Corrected. $\overset{\cdot\cdot}\smile$

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is flawed. The answer is one because any number $x: x \in \mathbb{R}$ \ $0$ divided by itself equals one.

Comment: Is 0/0 = 1?....

Comment: @recursiverecursion: it is usually best **not** to edit another's answer if only to correct a serious mistake. Such a correction is the answerer's responsibility (and choice).

Comment: Sorry about that.